# What's special about the zodiac weapons?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

Some chapters in *Kid Icarus: Uprising* have hidden rooms with special weapons in them, named after zodiac signs. For example, in chapter 2 you can find the Sagittarius Bow. These seem to be unique items; if you replay the level it's no longer in the room.

But at least as they are when you get them, they don't seem to be much better than the other weapons available.

Is there a way to improve them? Do they have other special abilities? Or should I be fusing them? If I do, is there a way to get another again later?

Comment: This is **NOT CONFIRMED**, but the word around the interwebz is that the zodiac weapons unlock the X-ed out slots in the weapon fusing grid.

Comment: That seems plausible. I have created some zodiac weapons from fusions, but only ones I already had.

Comment: Well, I haven't tried it myself but apparently the Zodiac weapons you find (not buy or fuse) are better to fuse with because they have good stats - or so I'm told. Truthfully, I'm only collecting them as part of the treasure hunt. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zodiac weapons...

- are required to [get a gold laurel wreath on the level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58446/what-do-i-need-to-do-for-a-gold-laurel-wreath).
- [unlock more weapon fusion options](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57737/why-are-some-weapon-fusions-blocked-out-with-a-question-mark), though they still don't seem to be special in any way.
- unlock a square in the Treasure Hunt grid, required for finishing the Treasure Hunt and 100% completion.