# What do I need to do for a gold laurel wreath?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

On the chapter select screen the ones I've finished are marked with a laurel wreath. Some of them are gold; some of them are green. It doesn't seem to be based on score (or at least not consistent across levels) or intensity; I thought it might be based on dying vs. not dying but my wife says she didn't die on some levels where she has green.

What decides if I get a gold wreath or a green one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know for sure, but for every one of mine that's gold I have gathered every treasure in that chapter.

Answer (score 3):

Yah the wreaths represent if you've opened every treasure chest, gone through all intensity gates, and found every zodiac item. Only then will the wreath be gold.

Comment: This is confirmed by [HeartBlade's walkthrough](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997768-kid-icarus-uprising/faqs/63997) "=Gold Wreath Requirements= 
-Open all chests (trapped ones included) 
-All intensity gates explored (if available) 
-Zodiac Weapon acquired (if available)"

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact collecting every item in the level.  This also makes the percentage for your file go up.  At least one level requires a difficulty of 9.0, so this is not an easy feat for every level.  Good luck to you and your quest for golden wreaths.  I wish everyone luck including myself on that haha.