# What do the wreath colors overlaying the chapters mean?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I need to do for a gold laurel wreath?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58446/what-do-i-need-to-do-for-a-gold-laurel-wreath)

I have been looking at my completed chapters and I noticed that some wreaths are green, while others are gold. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Gold wreaths mean you caught the secrets in the level (usually intensity doors) and green wreaths mean you still have a bit to go ;)