# Where are all the Zodiac Weapons located?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

[Zodiac Weapons are required to unlock a variety of things in the game.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57877/whats-special-about-the-zodiac-weapons) Due to this I want to make sure I find them all.

Which levels contain Zodiac Weapons, and where in each level are they located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all zodiac items are weapons; some are powers.

- **Sagittarius Bow:** *Chapter 2.* The chamber is hidden behind a tapestry; you can walk through it.
- **Taurus Arm:** *Chapter 4*. In the room with pendulums, fall down. Look for the hole that's emitting some light.
- **Gemini Orbitars:** *Chapter 6*. After the fight in the underground area, scale the wall until you find a pathway to the chamber entrance.
- **Cancer Claw:** *Chapter 8*. Instead of walking on the jump-pad in the area where the pirates keep their treasure, walk to the end of it and walk off, then go through the door.
- **Leo Cannon:** *Chapter 10*. Take the usual door out of the room with the statue you put in the lava, and keep hugging the left wall. The chamber entrance is obvious.
- **Virgo Palm:** *Chapter 12*. In a room with two bomb items, you normally step on an elevator platform to exit after defeating the enemies. Take the other elevator platform that wasn't there before.
- **Libra Sponge:** *Chapter 14*. In the room immediately before the boss, there is an electrified door. Dodge through it.
- **Scorpio Staff:** *Chapter 16*. There's a shaft you fall down; if you're still in the Ether Ring, you can find a passageway to the chamber right before the bottom.
- **Aries Armor:** *Chapter 18*. Left of the hot springs with the Souflee.
- **Capricorn Club:** *Chapter 20*. Walk through the wall in the last cell door on the left in the castle.
- **Aquarius Blade:** *Chapter 23*. In the part with the bunch of grind rails. At one point you switch rails to avoid falling down. Once you stop, get back on the rail you just came from.
- **Pisces Heal:** *Chapter 24*. When you're told to start the trials, go the other direction. It's an obvious path.

Comment: @Wipqozn: Yes, that's everything.

Answer (score 2):

- **Sagittarius Bow:** *Chapter 2*, walk through a large tapestry hanging on
  the wall that's located at the stairway.
- **Taurus Arm:** *Chapter 4*, fall down a blue-lit hole in the ground near
  other, purplish holes.
- **Gemini Orbitars**: *Chapter 6*, at the water fountain cross-section, go
  right to fight Dark Pit in the underground area (you may have to
  fight him at another location beforehand). After you beat him scale
  the wall until you find a pathway to the blue transport.
- **Cancer Claw:** *Chapter 8*, instead of walking on the jump-pad during one
  of the platform levels of the area where the space pirates keep their
  celestial treasure, walk to the end of it and walk off then go
  through the door there.
- **Leo Cannon:** *Chapter 10*, located past a door out of the room with the
  statue you put in the lava.
- **Capricorn Club:** *Chapter 20*, walk through the wall in the
  last cell door on the left in palutena's castle.

Comment: Welcome to the site Jake! In order to add a new line in your posts, you need to add two spaces at the end of the line (i.e. "HEllo! ") See [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The **Aquarius blade** is in Hades' intestines,in the part with the bunch of grind rails.  By following a certain one, you end up straight in the room it's in.

Answer (score 1):

At the reaper's place when you are at the jump pad to go to the top, don't jump.  Instead you can find a path that leads to an intensity door and good loot.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is one in chapter 4, in the Reaper Castle. It is where the chest is by a moving block that pushes you off to the lower levels. Look for a white light and jump down there.

Comment: The Reaper Castle is chapter 4, not 3. So far all the zodiac weapons I've found are in even-numbered levels.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Was probably just a typo. I edited in a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Sagitarrius bow is inside of the rug in chapter two. There is a side path somewhere in chapter 11 for Leo cannon. Virgo palm is in chapter 13 I think, and Aquarius blade is in Hades' belly.

Answer (score -1):

I know a palm one is in the first Veridi chapter, in the reset bomb impact zone. It's after the midair narrow path in the trunk of a tree or some short cave thing and a treasure fish goes by go to the right after you go through it.

Answer (score -1):

I found the Cancer Claws in Chapter 8. In the area with the compressed constellations go to first Jump Pad, then instead of the next pad, go the circular route, you'll notice a dead end. Drop off and go into the white light. You will then see a blue circle on the floor with light and a symbol above it. Go in the center of that circle. You'll see a hall and hear a strange sound.